# Redirects to same action from different urls in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2.

I am passing parameters via two urls. But it always goes to the first route only.

code in my routes.php is as follows:

```
Route::get('{department}', 'settings@load_department_settings')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('{id}', 'settings@load_staff')->middleware('auth');
```

Anchor tags in view is as follows:

```
<td><a href="/{{$staff->id}}">{{$staff->name}}</a></td>
<td><a href="/{{$staff->deptname}}">{{$staff->deptname}}</a></td>
```

The issue is it always uses 'settings@load_department_settings'. How could i use 'settings@load_staff' when clicking on staff name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always going to use the `{department}` route because that is matching anything on the root `/` slash. You need tto dive at least one of them unique prefixes. For example:

```
Route::get('department/{department}', 'settings@load_department_settings')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('staff/{id}', 'settings@load_staff')->middleware('auth');
```

Then

```
<td><a href="/staff/{{$staff->id}}">{{$staff->name}}</a></td>
<td><a href="/department/{{$staff->deptname}}">{{$staff->deptname}}</a></td>
```

Comment: No other ways to determine whether a department or staff is selected?

Comment: No as `'{department}'` will just match anything `'/sales', '/1'` etc.